# pytest with multiple jobs works, but create issue when use single job

Tags: python, environment-variables, pytest, pythonpath

I am using Mac. I installed `tox` to test my app.

When I use `pytest` with `-n0` option, it gives error for import module

```
root@localhost:myapp root$ .tox/py35/bin/py.test -n0
=============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/root/myapp, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.20.1, mock-1.6.3, forked-0.2, cov-2.2.1, celery-4.0.2
collected 2 items / 2 errors

===================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting app/tests/unit/test_utils.py __________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/root/myapp/app/tests/unit/test_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
app/tests/unit/test_utils.py:1: in <module>
    from app import utils
E   ImportError: No module named 'app'
__________________________________________________ ERROR collecting app/tests/unit/automation/collections/test_collection.py __________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/root/myapp/app/tests/unit/automation/collections/test_collection.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
app/tests/unit/automation/collections/test_collection.py:3: in <module>
    from app.automation.collections import collection
E   ImportError: No module named 'app'
============================================================================= pytest-warning summary ==============================================================================
WC1 None pytest_funcarg__cov: declaring fixtures using "pytest_funcarg__" prefix is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in pytest 4.0.  Please remove the prefix and use the @pytest.fixture decorator instead.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=================================================================== 1 pytest-warnings, 2 error in 1.27 seconds ====================================================================
```

But same command works with `-n5` option

```
root@localhost:myapp root$ .tox/py35/bin/py.test -n5
    =============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/root/myapp, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.20.1, mock-1.6.3, forked-0.2, cov-2.2.1, celery-4.0.2
gw0 [9] / gw1 [9] / gw2 [9] / gw3 [9] / gw4 [9]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling
.........
```

What it set in `-n5` which is not set for `-n0` ?

Comment: Have you tried by changing the package name `app` to something else? Because there's already a built-in python package with this same name. May be that causes the import error.

Comment: Thanks Chanda, I thought to change that, but if this is the case, then I not get a reason why it works with `-n 5` option.